# How to post result from controller to view in yii

Tags: php, templates, yii

[image]
I am trying to do following things...I have a page which is been used for searching as well as displaying results. I have done the following things, have a controller which is filtering data and I think its working fine till now..., but now  have no idea how to display the desired result in my view page.

```
/*Codes for Controller */

public function actionSearch()
{
    $model = new SearchEmployee();

    /*Getting Data From Search Form For Processing */
    if (isset($_POST['SearchEmployee'])) {

        $category   =  $_POST['SearchEmployee']['category_id'];
        $skills     =  $_POST['SearchEmployee']['skills'];
        $experience =  $_POST['SearchEmployee']['experience'];

        $model = SearchEmployee::model()->find(array(
            'select' => array('*'), "condition" => "category_id=$category AND key_skills like '%$skills%' AND experience=$experience",
        ));

        $this->render('search', array('model' => $model));
    }

    /*Getting Data From Search Form For Processing */
    $this->render('search', array('model' => $model));
}
```

In View: I have done like below, not posting full view, just portion of section where I have to show results.

```
<div class="view">

    <h1>Results </h1>

    <div class="view" id="id">

        <h1> Records Display </h1>

        <h4>Name:        <?php echo $model->name; ?></h4>
        <h4>Skills:      <?php echo $model->experience;?></h4>
        <h4>Experience:  <?php echo $model->key_skills; ?></h4>
        <h5>  <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('VIew Details'); ?></h5>
    </div>

</div>
```

I don't know whether I am on right track.

Comment: are you getting any error messages?

Comment: Are you trying to show multiple results or just one? If you use "find", it is to get only 1 result. For multiple results, use findAll.

Comment: @webeno,@Nathan...getting errror : 'Array to string conversion' in view line <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Category'); ?>

Comment: What should be my view like.?

Comment: if that's your error, you haven't included the relevant part of your view, as there is nothing in your code about `<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Category'); ?>`

Comment: when you ask a question, always share with us the results of what you did (error messages, screenshots, ...) and also what you WANT to see. We can't read your mind...

Comment: @saji did you finish the 8 chapters of the tutorial I sent you?

Comment: @saji , too many comments and details to go over. I created a chatroom for you: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50940/yii-framework  , bookmark it, and join me there once in a while. You can share this link with others that you think can help you with Yii programming.

Answer (score -1):

You should try with different word rather then model like modelData etc.

```
public function actionSearch()
{
    $model = new SearchEmployee();

    /*Getting Data From Search Form For Processing */
    if (isset($_POST['SearchEmployee'])) {

        $category   =  $_POST['SearchEmployee']['category_id'];
        $skills     =  $_POST['SearchEmployee']['skills'];
        $experience =  $_POST['SearchEmployee']['experience'];

        $modelData = SearchEmployee::model()->find(array(
            'select' => array('*'), "condition" => "category_id=$category AND key_skills like '%$skills%' AND experience=$experience",
        ));

        $this->render('search', array('model' => $model));
    }

    /*Getting Data From Search Form For Processing */
    $this->render('search', array('modelData' => $modelData));
}
```

Comment: Maverick..getting error..  Undefined variable: model